# Why are constructor-based injections preferred over property-based injections in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

The [nestjs docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#property-based-injection) describe two main approaches for injecting dependencies, **constructor-based** and **property-based** injection. It's also mentioned that constructor-based injections should be preferred over property-based injection where possible without any description why.

Is there any specific reason for this or is it just some kind of code style guide?

Answer (score 3):

Someone had asked the same thing on their discord but the answer isn't super clear... Here's a screenshot of the conversation:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

> WARNING
> If your class doesn't extend another provider, you should always prefer using constructor-based injection.

The nestjs docs does mention the reason to always prefer constructor-based injection. It states that if your class doesn't extend another provider then we should always use constructor-based injection.

What this means is that if your class has optional dependencies then you can use property-based injection otherwise you have to use constructor-based injection.

Consider, Class A which depends on Class B and Class A will not work if Class B is not injected in this case this is a mandatory dependency hence we have to use constructor-based injection.

Whereas, same Class A also depends on Class C but Class A will still work if Class C is not injected in this case it is an optional dependency hence we can use property-based injection here.

You can read more about this here:

https://khalilstemmler.com/articles/tutorials/dependency-injection-inversion-explained/
http://dillonbuchanan.com/programming/dependency-injection-constructor-vs-property/

Comment: But property-based injections are not optional in nestjs as far as I know? When I remove the provider of a property-based injection, the build fails as it would be with constructor-based injections. So I don't see a difference here.

The docs rather describe an advantage of property-based injections, which is, you don't have to pass the dependencies to the parent constructor in sub classes.